# Android shared element transition between an activity with a fragment to another activity with a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation

I have an ActivityA containing FragmentA and would like to make a shared element transition to ActivityB containing FragmentB.

In the activities the shared element would be the toolbar. In the fragments it would be a textview. Is there anyway to do this?

If not how could I make a shared element transition between both fragments in the activities?

Thanks in advance for any help. I have been stuck a while.

Okay so I will provide some code to clarify.

Here I have MainActivity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <!-- This is shared with DetailActivity -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:transitionName="sharedToolbar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- This contains MainFragment -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This activity contains this fragment called MainFragment:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!-- This element is shared with DetailFragment -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Fragment main"
        android:transitionName="sharedFragment"/>

    <!-- When this is clicked show next screen -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go to detail screen"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Now what I want to do is when I click the button in MainFragment I want to perform a fragment transaction to this activity called the DetailActivity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <!-- This is shared with MainActivity -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:transitionName="sharedToolbar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- This contains DetailFragment -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This activity contains this fragment called DetailFragment:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!-- This element is shared with MainFragment -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Fragment detail"
        android:transitionName="sharedFragment"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

As you can see in the code both activities share the toolbar and has the same transition name. Their containing fragments both have a textview which I would like to animate in the transition as well. These textviews also has the same transition name. Is there anyway to do this? I have tried and so far I could only animate the toolbar between the two activities. How do I make the fragments perform a shared element transition at the same time?

If this can't be done, how could I make it so when I navigate from MainActivity to DetailActivity that the textview of the fragments are what appears as the transition so not the toolbars(If I cant animate activity and fragment transactions at the same time).

Comment: plz post your what you are try?

Comment: @DaminiMehra SMS English format doesn't work here, Hope you get the whole point why people ask questions here.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this tutorials: https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations

Answer (score 0):

Facing a similar issue. My mistake is with the kind of architectural decision I made. One activity, multiple fragments for every individual flow causes this issue. Now I can not have desired transitions when switching between flows because that required loading an activity and a fragment.

Firstly, change the background color of your fragment containing activity to your app's default background color. My app's default background color was grey and a white background of container activity was looking really bad. A grey background looks less bad.

Now, remove default transition from container activity. This can be done by using 
`overridePendingTransition(0,0);`

Now things will look less ugly.
It is just a work around.